# fs_data_dirs must contain at least one data directory error in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Just exploring YugabyteDB for a large application, and trying to get a private cluster set up. On the first yb-master I can start yb_master with the following command:

```
/root/yugabyte-2.11.1.0/bin/yb-master --replication_factor=3 --fs_data_dirs "/data"
```

I tried to set these in a flagfile as such:

```
/root/yugabyte-2.11.1.0/bin/yb-master --flagfile=/yugabyte/config/ybmaster.conf
```

My file:

```
cat /yugabyte/config/ybmaster.conf
{
    "fs_data_dirs": "/data",
    "replication_factor": 3
}
```

When I run it:

```
Invalid argument (yb/util/init.cc:96): Cannot initialize logging. Flag fs_data_dirs (a comma-separated list of data directories) must contain at least one data directory.
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with my flagfile? Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your flag file doesn't look right, it needs to be in this format:

```
--flag=value
--flag=value
```

And not in JSON like you did.